# ng-disabled option in angular ui-select shrinks the text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2

I am using angular ui-select directive and trying to disable it with ng-disabled option.

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="address.selected"
             theme="bootstrap"
             ng-disabled="true"
             reset-search-input="true"
             style="width: 300px;">
```

Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/julETCG4zCGAxFJ0PSBF?p=preview

Size of the text box shrinks with ng-disabled="true".

Comment: Your plunkr has errors in the console that prevent it from running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update `theme` from `bootstrap` to `select2` as shown below:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="address.selected"
         theme="select2"
         ng-disabled="true"
         reset-search-input="true"
         style="width: 300px;">
```

If you want `bootstrap` theme then add this to style instead:

```
.ui-select-multiple.ui-select-bootstrap {
    min-height: 34px;        
    height: auto;
    padding: .3em;
}
```

as shown [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/aTxSuqHP6bpxfpMEfCLU?p=preview).

Comment: This was huge for me. Thank You